# AngularJS: Access controller properties inside script tag in the view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In app.js I have a controller wrapped in a closure:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('areaInfo', function($http){...});
})()
```

In index.html, I have:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="areaInfo as ctrlAreaInfo">...</body>
```

I have no trouble accessing the controller's properties in HTML between the body tags, but now I need to access its properties within a `<script>` tag like so:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="areaInfo as ctrlAreaInfo">
...
<script>
var myVar = ctrlAreaInfo.property;
</script>
</body>
```

Obviously, the code above doesn't work; so how would I access a controller's property from within a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Why do you want to access the property in a different script tag?

Comment: Because I am including Google maps in the view, but need to input the lat/lng stored in the controller

Comment: Then most likely you are doing something wrong

Comment: Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/pc7Uu/854/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using ngMap (https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) to display Google Maps and it works like a charm.